Dataflow pipeline running out of disk space maybe because of accumulating files on worker?
We have a dataflow pipeline which collects thousand of parquet files in a bucket, does some transformations and concatenate them all together. However when we increase the number of files we want to process (for instance doubling the number of files), we often encounter crashing workers because they are running out of disk space.
We confirmed this by running the same pipeline with more disk space (~500Gb instead of the standard 20Gb) which works.
However we do not understand where all this disk utilization is coming from. The final output is around 1Gb usually and the raw base files around 2-4Mb each. We suspect that the base files are somehow opened on workers and accumulating because they are not properly closed but we don't know how to confirm this.
Here's our pipeline:
import appache_beam as beam
import pandas as pd

class GetFileList(beam.DoFn):
    def process(
        self, element,
    ) -> Iterator[str]:
        blob_names = GcsIO().list_files(
            f"gs://bucket_name",
        )
        for blob in blob_names:
            yield blob

class DownloadFile(beam.DoFn):
     def process(
        self, element,
     ) -> Iterator[tuple[str, pd.Dataframe]]:
     with GcsIO().open(file_name, "rb") as file:
          yield get_grouping_key(file_name), do_transformations(pd.read_parquet(file))

def concat_and_export(element: tuple[str, list[pd.Dataframe]):
   df = pd.concat(element[1]
   with GcsIO().open(file_name, "w") as file:
       df.to_parquet(file)


with beam.pipeline.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    (pipeline
    | "Initialize ">> beam.Create(None)
    | "Get list of files"   >> beam.ParDo(GetFileList())
    | "Reshuffle to prevent fusing and distribute between workers" >> beam.Reshuffle()
    | "Download files"      >> beam.ParDo(DownloadFile())
    | "Group by"  >>  beam.GroupByKey()
    | "Concatenate and export results to bucket" >> beam.Map(concat_and_export)



Hi @unitrium, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

Do you need this?
with GcsIO().open(file_name, "w") as file:
df.to_parquet(file)
This should work:
df.to_parquet("gs:///file.parquet",
storage_options={"token": }
